# Spawn GUI child process in Node.js but hide the GUI

Tags: node.js, user-interface, child-process

My Node.js application uses `child_process` to spawn a child process that opens its own GUI window. I wish that the process runs, but the GUI doesn't show at all. Is this possible to do purely in Node?

Comment: Update: since this does not seem possible in Node, I decided to use a solution that lies outside of Node.js.